# Making a sequence strictly increasing by joining neighboring numbers using the smallest number of moves

Tags: algorithms

I've got a following problem to solve:

```
You are given a list of positive integers [x_1;x_2;...;x_n]. You are allowed to 
change 2 integers standing next to each other to one equal to their sum. (So for
example in list [x_1;...;x_3;x_4;x_5;x_6;...;x_n] you pick x_4 and x_5 and the new list
becomes [x_1;...;x_3;(x_4+x_5);x_6;...;x_n]). Find the minimum number of such changes
needed to get a list in which integers are in strictly increasing order.
```

How to approach such a problem? Intuitively it looks like Dynamic Programming problem (something like multiplying matrices) but I cannot find any connected subproblems. Any idea how to solve this using something else than brute-force?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this needs DP. I can't see a good reason why a simple greedy algorithm wouldn't work. (I.e. go through the sequence, whenever you get a number out of order, merge it with either left or right. Left only if it wouldn't make the right number out-of-order)

Comment: Thought of this too, but I cannot see how to prove it and as this task is in my workbook under "dynamic programming" chapter, I think it's possible that this approach could be wrong for some cases...

Answer (score 3):

I would use an [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). A* is a best-first search using always the node with the lowest total cost `g(l)+h(l)`, where `g` is the "past path cost function" and `h` is the "future path-cost function". The search space is a graph where each node is one of the possible lists you can reach by subsequent adding of two numbers, starting with your initial list. The edges of the graph are defined by the moves. The past path-cost function `g(l)` is given by the number of moves so far to reach the list `l`. The future path-cost function `h(l)` is given by the number of pairs `(x_i,x_(i+1))` in the list `l` where `x_(i+1)` is less or equal to `x_i`. For example, when `h(l)=0`, the list `l` is strictly increasing and you reached an end node in your graph.

Note that **each move can reduce the number of such pairs by one at maximum**, so `h` will be never an overestimation, which guarantees the A* search will find the optimal solution.

For this kind of problem, it will certainly make sense to avoid having the same list `l` analysed twice, since the same list can be reached by different sequences of summation. So during the search, store every list (=graph node visited) in a hash set and prune the search when reaching the same list again.

Answer (score -1):

If you are allowed to combine multiple times, just sum all the numbers into a single value.  A list of one number is sorted :)  So the number of moves is n-1.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the maximum number of changes?

Comment: If the numbers are already in order, the minimum number of moves is zero.  If you consider checking the order as a "move", then you need to make at least n-1 comparisons.  With these comparisons considered, n-1 would, in fact, be both a minimum and a maximum.

Comment: Checking the order is not a "move", only joining numbers is...

Comment: And n-1 is clearly not the answer, consider [1;2;3;4;7;6], then the answer is actually one (you can join last 2 numbers to get 13 and the resulting list [1;2;3;4;13] is strictly increasing)